# Bean instantiation via factory method failed; exception org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have the following Spring configuration for Kafka:

```
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.cloud.context.config.annotation.RefreshScope;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.ProducerFactory;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

@Configuration
@RefreshScope
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "kafka.status.producer")
public class StatusKafkaProducerConfig {

  private String keySerializer;
  private String valueSerializer;
  private String bootstrapServers;

  public void setKeySerializer(String keySerializer) {
    this.keySerializer = keySerializer;
  }

  public void setValueSerializer(String valueSerializer) {
    this.valueSerializer = valueSerializer;
  }

  public void setBootstrapServers(String bootstrapServers) {
    this.bootstrapServers = bootstrapServers;
  }

  @Bean
  public Map<String, Object> producerConfigs() {
    Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();

    properties.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, keySerializer);
    properties.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, valueSerializer);
    properties.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);

    return properties;
  }

  @Bean
  @RefreshScope
  public KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate() {
    return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
  }

  @Bean
  public ProducerFactory<String, String> producerFactory() {
    return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(producerConfigs());
  }    
}
```

I migrated the project to latest Spring cloud 2021.0.1 and Spring Boot 2.6.6. But I get the following error stack during boot time:

```
    2022-04-30 19:14:08.350 ERROR 23684 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'producerFactory' defined in class path resource [com/test/StatusUpdateKafkaProducerConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.kafka.core.ProducerFactory]: Factory method 'producerFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:486) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:953) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:740) ~[spring-boot-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:415) ~[spring-boot-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) ~[spring-boot-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1312) ~[spring-boot-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301) ~[spring-boot-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
    at com.test.Application.main(Application.java:82) ~[main/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.kafka.core.ProducerFactory]: Factory method 'producerFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.putVal(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1011) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.putAll(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1089) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.<init>(ConcurrentHashMap.java:852) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory.<init>(DefaultKafkaProducerFactory.java:205) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.5.jar:2.8.5]
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory.<init>(DefaultKafkaProducerFactory.java:168) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.5.jar:2.8.5]
    at com.test.StatusUpdateKafkaProducerConfig.producerFactory(TransactionStatusUpdateKafkaProducerConfig.java:53) ~[commons-0.0.1-plain.jar:na]
    at com.test.StatusUpdateKafkaProducerConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e907de88.CGLIB$producerFactory$0(<generated>) ~[commons-0.0.1-plain.jar:na]
    at com.test.StatusUpdateKafkaProducerConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e907de88$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$db10662a.invoke(<generated>) ~[commons-0.0.1-plain.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) ~[spring-core-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331) ~[spring-context-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at com.StatusUpdateKafkaProducerConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e907de88.producerFactory(<generated>) ~[commons-0.0.1-plain.jar:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:282) ~[spring-core-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope$LockedScopedProxyFactoryBean.invoke(GenericScope.java:485) ~[spring-cloud-context-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763) ~[spring-aop-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:708) ~[spring-aop-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at com.StatusUpdateKafkaProducerConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6800bd04.producerFactory(<generated>) ~[commons-0.0.1-plain.jar:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
```

Do you know how I can fix this issue?

Comment: Take a detailed look at the module names in the error message. Do you see the difference?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error stack trace is indicating that a `NullPointerException` is happening when you are creating a new instance of `DefaultKafkaProducerFactory` in the `producerFactory()` method.

Internally, `DefaultKafkaProducerFactory` [creates a `ConcurrentHashMap`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/blob/b0102611d05732a8c93bb51c413fc6f8680b1ae2/spring-kafka/src/main/java/org/springframework/kafka/core/DefaultKafkaProducerFactory.java#L205) with the provided information to maintain its configuration.

As you can see in the [`ConcurrentHashMap` javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#put-K-V-), the `put` method will raise `NullPointerException` if any of the provided keys or values are `null`.

As a consequence, probably one of or several of the variables `keySerializer`, `valueSerializer` or `bootstrapServers` are null.

I assume these values are filled by dependency injection according to your `@ConfigurationProperties` `kafka.status.producer`. Please, be sure these properties are correctly defined in your Spring configuration.

For testing purposes, try removing the `@RefreshScope` annotation: it may be a cause of the problem.

The contrary can be a valid solution as well. As indicated in the Spring Cloud documentation when [talking about `@RefreshScope`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-commons/docs/3.1.2/reference/html/#refresh-scope):

> `@RefreshScope` works (technically) on a `@Configuration` class,
> but it might lead to surprising behavior. For example, it does not
> mean that all the `@Beans` defined in that class are themselves in
> `@RefreshScope`. Specifically, anything that depends on those beans
> cannot rely on them being updated when a refresh is initiated, unless
> it is itself in `@RefreshScope`. In that case, it is rebuilt on a
> refresh and its dependencies are re-injected. At that point, they are
> re-initialized from the refreshed `@Configuration`).

From that point of view if make perfect sense to annotate with `@RefreshScope` the `producerFactory` bean as well. I would try:

```java
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.cloud.context.config.annotation.RefreshScope;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.ProducerFactory;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

@Configuration
@RefreshScope
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "kafka.status.producer")
public class StatusKafkaProducerConfig {

  private String keySerializer;
  private String valueSerializer;
  private String bootstrapServers;

  public void setKeySerializer(String keySerializer) {
    this.keySerializer = keySerializer;
  }

  public void setValueSerializer(String valueSerializer) {
    this.valueSerializer = valueSerializer;
  }

  public void setBootstrapServers(String bootstrapServers) {
    this.bootstrapServers = bootstrapServers;
  }

  @Bean
  @RefreshScope
  public Map<String, Object> producerConfigs() {
    Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();

    properties.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, keySerializer);
    properties.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, valueSerializer);
    properties.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);

    return properties;
  }

  @Bean
  @RefreshScope
  public KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate() {
    return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
  }

  @Bean
  @RefreshScope
  public ProducerFactory<String, String> producerFactory() {
    return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(producerConfigs());
  }    
}
```

Please, note the inclusion of the additional `@RefreshScope` annotations.

Finally, consider review the Spring Kafka project documentation, it provides several examples about how to configure your project, whether you are using [Spring Boot](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#spring-boot-producer-app) or [not](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#with-java-configuration-no-spring-boot), and gives you further background about [`DefaultKafkaProducerFactory`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#producer-factory).

As you can see in the aforementioned docs, if you are using Spring Boot, like in you case, the code can be greatly simplified. Consider review the [`Spring Boot` related documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/messaging.html#messaging.kafka) about the subject and [related properties configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#application-properties.integration.spring.kafka.producer.bootstrap-servers).

Comment: Any feedback on this Peter? I realize your new question. Does it mean that the suggested approach worked properly?

Comment: I edited the answer with an additional approach. I hope it helps.